# How do I use a compressed columnar store in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Objective:

I'd like to user Spark on a sparse dataset.  I understand that SparkSQL now supports columnar data stores (I believe via SchemaRDD).  I've been told that compression of the columnar store is implemented but currently turned off by default.

I can make sure that Spark is store my my dataset as a compressed, in memory, columnar store?

What I've Tried:

At the Spark Summit, someone told me that I have to turn on compression as follows:

```
conf.set("spark.sql.inMemoryStorage.compressed", "true")
```

However, doing so doesn't seem to make any difference in my memory footprint.

The following are snippets of my test code:

```
case class Record(i: Int, j: Int)
...
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
conf.set("spark.sql.inMemoryStorage.compressed", "true")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
val records = // create an RDD of 1M Records
val table = createSchemaRDD(records)
table.cache
```

In one case, I create records so that all the values of i and j are unique.  In this case, I see that 89.4MB are used.

In a second case, I create records so that most of the values of i and j are 0.  (Roughly 99.9% of the entries are 0).  In this case, I see that 43.0MB are used.

I expected a much higher compression ratio.  Is there something I should do differently?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting you want to use in Spark 1.0.2 is:

`spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed`

Just set it to "true".  I do it in my `conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

Just verified that this yields smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlContext.cacheTable` is needed. `.cache` will not cache the table with the in-memory columnar store.

Comment: Looks like it is the case now, isn't it ? *"Spark SQL can cache tables using an in-memory columnar format by calling spark.catalog.cacheTable("tableName") or dataFrame.cache()"* ([from official doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#caching-data-in-memory))

Comment: I try this but I can't confirm that spark.catalog.cacheTable("tableName") or dataFrame.cache()" cache tables using an in-memory columnar format !
not working for me...